# Outlook 2003: what's the difference between "contacts" and "contacts in personal folders"?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

What is the difference between "contacts" and "contacts in personal folders"?  For that matter, what is the difference between "calendar" and "calendar in personal folders"?

We seem to have both and the contents of each seem identical.

Answer (score 0):

Different names. IIRC, Personal Folders is for your main account and is always online, while the other is the offline copy of everything... That may be mixe up though

Comment: On another computer here, there are two "calendar" entries and a "calendar in archive folders" but no "personal folders"

Answer (score 0):

The account likley has a PST with Contacts and the Exchange contacts.  The Contacts in Personal Folder are in the PST  In the same way there is an Archive folder (default name Archive.pst) that has calendar entries.

You can be using Exchange and attach archive folders and Personal Folders. Usually someone has used File-Open-Outlook Data File.  You will see these folders in the tree view of Outlook.